# How do I make browser window always-on-top (or bottom) whenever I open the broswer?

Tags: firefox, window-manager, browser, window-management, wmctrl

(Actually I want it to be always-on-bottom, but "on-top" is a more common search term).

I know that I can use

```
wmctrl -r "Mozilla Firefox" -b toggle,below
```

to set the browser window to be always-below, but how can I set it automatically every time I open the browser?

Comment: What window manager are you using?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu with LXDE I guess...